# Find which table has that column data

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to find which table has that column name, by running:

```
select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where column_name = 'column value'
```

What i need now, is to find which tables have that certain column data.
It doesn't matter which column it belongs, I can find it, i just don't know which table to look at.

Joining these tables is not a solution, since there are a lot of tables.

Pls. let me know if you have ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: Practically, you'll have to get a list of all the possible tables (probably all in one particular schema?) and then query each of them.

Comment: that's kinda hard. if you would do it that way, querying all your tables for a specific column value, it would be kinda slow and heavy. you should consider @DariusX's suggestion

Comment: You have to narrow down your searching efforts. Of what type is your searching term (int, varchar  etc)? **Give a relevant example.** In columns of what type are you expecting your value to be present (int, varchar, etc)? What are types  (decimal, datetime, timestamp) and (or) name patterns (e.g. 'id', '%_id', etc) for columns that should be **excluded** from the search list.

Comment: joining the tables is THE solution. otherwise, consider a redesign, or duplicating the relevant table data in a more search friendly structure.

Comment: SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login="" to find that that column have  blank or not  data

Answer (score 1):

Will this do the job for you?

```
declare @data varchar(50)
    ,@sql varchar(max)
select @data = '%test%'

create table #Temp ([Table] varchar(200), [Column] varchar(200), [Data] varchar(max))

select @sql = isnull(@sql, '') + 'insert into #Temp select ''' + sys.tables.name + ''', ''' + sys.columns.name + ''', ' + sys.columns.name + ' from [' + sys.tables.name + '] where [' + sys.columns.name + '] like ''' + @data + ''';'
from sys.tables
inner join sys.columns
    on sys.columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id

exec(@sql)

select * from #Temp order by [Table], [Column]
drop table #Temp
```

Comment: ah..ok. so, there's sys.tables, and sys.columns? will try this. thanks